# what's different between "mc cp --recursive" and "mc mirror --overwrite"

Tags: minio

If we want to copy a bucket to another MiniO cluster, should we use "mc cp" or "mc mirror"? I have done some simple experiments and it seems that they are the same.

Thank~!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Short answer

Yes, `mc cp --recursive SOURCE TARGET` and `mc mirror --overwrite SOURCE TARGET` will have the same effect (to the best of my experience as of 2022-01).

- `mc cp` allows for fine-tuned options for single files (but can bulk copy using `--recursive`)
- `mc mirror` is focussed on bulk copying and can create buckets

Looking at the [Minio client guide](https://docs.min.io/docs/minio-client-complete-guide.html), there are several differences between the `mc mirror` and the `mc cp` commands, although the result of running them *can* be the same.

The answer to which one *should* you use depends on your requirements, and both options may be acceptable for you.

### Details

The command signature differ: `mc cp` allows for multiple sources while `mc mirror` only allows for a single source.

In addition, the available flags are somewhat different (see below).

#### Flags `mc cp` offers not offered by `mc mirror`

1. `--rewind value`: roll back object(s) to current version at specified time
2. `--version-id value`, `--vid value`: select an object version to copy
3. `--attr`: add custom metadata for the object (format: `KeyName1=string;KeyName2=string`)
4. `--continue`, `-c`: create or resume copy session
5. `--tags`: apply tags to the uploaded objects (eg. `key=value&key2=value2`, etc)
6. `--rewind value`: roll back object(s) to current version at specified time
7. (The `--recursive`, `-r` flag, but that's always true for `mirror`)

Flags offered by `mc mirror` not offered by `mc clone`:

#### Flags `mc mirror` offers not offered by `mc cp`

1. `--exclude value`: exclude object(s) that match specified object name pattern
2. `--fake`: perform a fake mirror operation
3. `--overwrite`: overwrite object(s) on target if it differs from source
4. `--region value`: specify region when creating new bucket(s) on target (default: "us-east-1")
5. `--watch`, `-w`: watch and synchronize changes **(This may be a big deal)**

Consider using [`rclone`](https://rclone.org/) as an alternative with additional flexibility.  The Minio project is focussed on performance and being an excellent, simple S3 backend, not implementing every feature you could ask for (e.g., chunk size, throttling).

Answer (score 1):

Important to note:

mc mirror only synchronizes the current object without any version information or metadata. To synchronize an object’s version history and metadata, consider using mc replicate or mc admin replicate.

https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/reference/minio-mc/mc-mirror.html

Answer (score 1):

@Gordon Fogus: you forgot to mention that `mc mirror` has also the `--remove` flag in order to be sure that a file removed in remote is also removed in local.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/32938182)